# Batch file start appliction and pass multiple parameters switches spaces to á

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I created an c# wpf application that accepts command line parameters. If I open cmd and call the application with multiple parameters, the parameters are passed in correctly.

But if I do that same thing but from a batch file it passes the parameters as one parameter combined together rather then multiple parameters. I had the application output the parameters and it looks like all the spaces (which is what separates each command line parameter) were changed to a weird `á` character.
is there something special I need to do to get the parameters passed correctly?

I have tried resaving the file with ASCII encoding but that didn't change anything.
I also tried adding this line to the batch file

```
chcp 1253>NUL
```

that changed it so the `á` wasn't there but it still had it was one parameter.
seems like the spaces are just not getting passed as a space.

here is what my batch file line looks like, each parameter is separated by a space.

```
start /wait C:\MyTestApp.exe /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE
```

--UPDATE--Adding steps to reproduce...

this is just generic code similar to what I did just condensed

create c# wpf app.

in App.xaml.cs override OnStartup

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
    bool shutdownapp = false;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", e.Args));
}
```

build exe.

now launch cmd and cd to the location of the exe.

```
 MyTestApp.exe /param1=test1 /param2=test2
```

you should get a message box that says

/param1=test1,param2=test2

now create a batch file that has something like this...then run it

test.bat

```
@echo off
start /wait c:\MyTestApp.exe /param1=test1 /param2=test2
```

this time the message box should have this...
/param1=test1/param2=test2

Comment: Could you provide a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Also what are your locale settings? Are you sure that in the batch you have spaces (check with a hex editor)?

Comment: What why are you using Start?  Just put this in your CMD Script: `C:\MyTestApp.exe" /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE`

Comment: wow I feel pretty stupid..thanks to CristiFati I removed what I thought was a space and readded it and it then worked.. have no idea how my spaces got to be not spaces. way to much time wasted on this..thanks

Comment: CristiFati, could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered, since you did in fact solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Start sees all of that as a CMD to Start.

Is there a reason you actually need to use start?  generally, there isn't and you can just call the executable directly.

### eg TestMyApp.cmd

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
)

REM Call your Command here with all arguments:
"C:\MyTestApp.exe" /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE
```

If you sincerely require Start.

Then you should be aware that it treats all of that command as a single string, by nature, which is what you're running into, so you should be calling a new CMD instance explicitly instead in that case:

```
START "" /WAIT CMD /C ""C:\MyTestApp.exe" /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE"
```

But that is a lot of extra work to go through if not needed.

Alternatively, you can also just run a CMD instance directly:

```
 CMD /C ""C:\MyTestApp.exe" /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE"
```

Or Use CALL:

CALL "C:\MyTestApp.exe" /SILENT /BOOLAGREEMENT=TRUE /BOOLGAOPTIN=TRUE